# Spring profile, code based config and JNDI

Tags: spring, jndi, spring-profiles

I am moving to new Spring 3.x code based @Configuration style. I have done good, so far, but when I tried to add a @Profile("production") to select a JNDI data source instead of C3p0 connection pool @Profile("standalone"), I've got:

```
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
...
```

Of course, there is a lot of details (I included some below for reference), but my question is: would someone kindly post/point to a working example?

Thanks,

Details:

- Same configuration, as XML, is working fine,
- web.xml points to a root context configured in AppConfig.class and to a servlet context configured in WebConfig.class,
- AppConfig has an @Import(SomeConfig.class) pulling a config from a service layer project - dependencies are wired by maven,
- The SomeConfig class has the @Profile("standalone") on the C3p0 datasource,
- The AppConfig class has the @Profile("production") on the JNDI datasource,
  web.xml defines spring.profiles.default=production.

**Edit: Solved**

I moved the profile to the right place. Now they are in the same file and in the same project:

```
...
other bean definitions

/**
 * Stand-alone mode of operation.
 */
@Configuration
@Profile("standalone")
static class StandaloneProfile {

    @Autowired 
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * Data source.
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
            ds.setDriverClass(env.getRequiredProperty("helianto.jdbc.driverClassName"));
            ds.setJdbcUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("helianto.jdbc.url"));
            ds.setUser(env.getRequiredProperty("helianto.jdbc.username"));
            ds.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("helianto.jdbc.password"));
            ds.setAcquireIncrement(5);
            ds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
            ds.setMaxPoolSize(100);
            ds.setMaxStatements(50);
            ds.setMinPoolSize(10);
            return ds;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Production mode of operation.
 */
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
static class ProductionProfile {

    @Autowired 
    private Environment env;

    /**
     * JNDI data source.
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
            jndiFactory.setJndiName("java:comp/env/jdbc/heliantoDB");
            jndiFactory.afterPropertiesSet(); //edited: do not forget this!
            return (DataSource) jndiFactory.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code/configuration?

Comment: And when you do post your code, please include the full stacktrace.